# Express static folder does not load properly

Tags: node.js, angular, express, static

I'm having trouble with a Node APP that I am building.

App folder structure:

- controllers // controllers
- helpers // helpers
- config // some config files
- public // stores a built angular app
- ...

App URL 1: www.domain.com
App URL 2: www.another.com/myapps/app1

So this is how I set the static folder to load the assets:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

And this is how I would access the files in the static folder:

```
URL1: www.domain.com/assets/main.js
URL2: www.another.com/myapps/app1/assets/main.js
```

Now, the problem is that if I deploy the app on URL1 everything works perfectly. But deploying the app to URL2 gives me some issues.

The static files cannot be accessed on the app on URL2. I get 404 (Cannot GET ...).

```
www.another.com/myapps/app1/assets/main.js // returns 404
www.domain.com/assets/main.js // returns the JavaScript file.
```

There are multiple apps running on URL2 that is why I have used contexts to separate the apps. 
My initial thoughts are that because of the additional contexts to the url on URL2, express is failing to set the static folder properly.

Could this be because the static folder is not being set properly?

Answer (score 0):

`express.static` receives data from somewhere and applies this data to the root of your domain.
Actually you can get your files inside another folder by adding some structure.
In your case set `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` and place **assets** inside **app1** and then in **myapps** folders. All this should be inside **public** folder

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more. 
If express.static applies this to the root, is there a way to change it to apply the data to the context (/myapps/app1/)

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I think I didn't mention that /myapps/app1 is not a folder. This is a url that is mapped to my application. 

So if you go to www.another.co.za/myapps/app1, there are some Network routing rules that pass the request to my application.

So there are three applications on that url:
www.another.com/myapps/app1/  = this is my app
www.another.com/myapps/app2/ = There is another app running here
www.another.com/  = There is another app running here